# Send download token in header of GET request

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I am new to firebase. I have this url where download token is sent as query param. This is not secure as url can be logged and token will be exposed.

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sync-dev-30d7c.appspot.com/o/-MJ_drtw43bNU55JPyus%2Fslideshow%2F1607934794881?alt=media&token=d7ab741a-9353-4997-99c3-5fb800f6ea09

Is there a way to not send token in url and send it in body and header?

Comment: What exactly were you doing before that no longer works?  Please edit the question to be clear, showing all relevant code.  If you are following any documentation, please link that for reference.  As far as I know, Firebase Storage has never accepted anything other than the download token in the URL.  The URLs are not meant to be secure, just private to whomever has the URL.

Comment: I might be mistaken about token in header working. I have removed that part. Does firebase team accept feature requests? I can create a issue on firebase storage github.